# How to show a succes message on form submission in wordpress redirect

Tags: wordpress, forms, post, redirect

i currently have a large form on a wordpress template page, that get submitted to it self, in order to validate the data. If the data looks good, then the data is stored in the database.

this all works fine, but I have 2 related problems.

1. If you refresh the page, the data gets inserted again. In order to get around this, i wanted to do a page redirect, which would leed to my next problem:
2. On a re-direct, I no longer have access to the posted data, so my success page cant show the info that they posted. This is crucial.

So how should i work around that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this (rookie suggestion):

Create a template page inside your theme folder containing a PHP script to show the data from MySQL using a session or cookie variable on redirect.
Via a SELECT function, you can load op the data the user posted on that template page.

Create a page inside WordPress, name it "thank you" and call in the template you created in your theme folder.
You can find the template in the sidebar under Page-Attribute.

Redirect the user to that "thank you"-page after they submit your form.

By using this method:

1. A user is able to refresh the page without having a re-input in MySQL
2. You can customize that template page as much as you want

Comment: would there be a way to do it without using sessions or cookies?

Comment: yeah, that wouldn't work, as im not registering users. Okay i'll look into the session thing then. Thanks. I feel like there should be a simpler way though.